# как сделать привязку по времени?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

В общем у меня есть БД в которой я хочу сделать привязку по времени. Как это?
В общем, пользователь вносит данные о своих доходах/расходах и эти данные согласно месяцу внесения были отправлены в одну из таблиц. Как это сделать корректно? Я так понимаю использовать datetime, но как это вообще должно выглядеть?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["create_ex"])
def create_func(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '''Идёт создание таблицы.
                            Секундочку...''')
    # df = pd.DataFrame({'Личный доход': [],
    #     'Расходы': []
    #                   })

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '''Готово!
                Можешь взглянуть на свою таблицу:''')
    db = sqlite3.connect("finothc2test.db")
    cur = db.cursor()
    
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE january (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Январь_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Январь_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Январь_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Январь_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Январь_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Январь_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Январь_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Январь_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE february (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Февраль_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Февраль_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Февраль_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Февраль_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Февраль_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Февраль_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Февраль_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Февраль_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE march (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Март_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Март_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Март_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Март_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Март_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Март_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Март_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Март_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE april (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Апрель_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Апрель_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Апрель_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Апрель_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Апрель_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Апрель_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Апрель_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Апрель_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE may (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Май_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Май_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Май_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Май_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Май_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Май_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Май_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Май_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE june (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Июнь_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июнь_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июнь_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июнь_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июнь_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июнь_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июнь_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июнь_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE july (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Июль_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июль_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июль_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июль_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июль_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июль_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июль_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Июль_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE august (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Август_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Август_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Август_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Август_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Август_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Август_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Август_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Август_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE september (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Сентябрь_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Сентябрь_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Сентябрь_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Сентябрь_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Сентябрь_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Сентябрь_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Сентябрь_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Сентябрь_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE october (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Октябрь_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Октябрь_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Октябрь_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Октябрь_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Октябрь_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Октябрь_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Октябрь_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Октябрь_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE november (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Ноябрь_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Ноябрь_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Ноябрь_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Ноябрь_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Ноябрь_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Ноябрь_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Ноябрь_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Ноябрь_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE december (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Декабрь_Доход INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Декабрь_Премия INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Декабрь_Коммунальыне платежи INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Декабрь_Проезд INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Декабрь_Необходимые расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Декабрь_Развлечения INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Декабрь_Вклады_и_инвестиции INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        Декабрь_Непредвиденные расходы INTEGER DEFAULT 0

        )''')
```

Как сам ввод должен работать я понимаю, но вот с привязкой по времени понять не могу(

Comment: *пользователь вносит данные о своих доходах/расходах и эти данные согласно месяцу внесения были отправлены в одну из таблиц. Как это сделать корректно?* Это само по себе некорректно - несколько таблиц для однотипных данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректнее будет не создавать отдельные таблицы, а иначе со временем придется создавать большое количество БД. Лучше создать стоблец в БД для хранения времени создания записи.
Например можно использовать Integer и хранить в нём время в секундах с начала эпохи UNIX (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC)

```
CREATE TABLE money
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
created_time INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

При сохранении можно использовать встроенные функции SQLite

```
INSERT INTO money (created_time)
VALUES (strftime('%s', 'now'));
```

Если такая точность не нужна можно создать свою структуру и хранить уже не в секундах, а в днях или в месяцах